# sum of a string contains a sequence of decimal numbers

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm really a starter in programming. I want to prints the sum of a string s = '1.23,2.4,3.123'.
I tried to use

```
total = 0.0
for s in '1.23,2.4,3.123':
    total += float(s)
print total
```

but it doesn't work, could anyone help?
THX a lot

Comment: split the string and then transform to float

Comment: what exactly are you expecting to happen? how would it know you want to split on commas and interpret each segment of the string as a number? computers are dumb; you have to tell it exactly what you want to do ;)

Answer (score 3):

You could try the following:

```
total = sum(float(i) for i in s.split(','))
```

It runs like this:

- `s.split(',')` pulls out each 'number' in the string
- `float(i) for i in s...` makes a float of each split value
- `sum()` adds them all up

Hope this helps!

Comment: Please note that there's no need to make it a `list`. It looks simpler and is faster as a generator: `sum(float(i) for i in s.split(','))`.

Comment: I like that! will edit above

Answer (score 1):

```
s = '1.23,2.4,3.123'
nums = [float(i) for i in s.split(',')] # creates a list of floats split by ','
print sum(nums) # prints the sum of the values
```

Comment: Think you're missing a type conversion there...

Comment: @JonClements Yeah realized that after I actually tried it. Thanks :)

Comment: `sum(ast.literal_eval(s))` is also possible ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> str_list = '1.23,2.4,3.123'.split(',')
>>> float_list = [float(str_number) for str_number in str_list]
>>> total = sum(float_list)
>>> print total
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it this way:

```
sum(map(float, s.split(',')))
```

Comment: List comprehensions or, even better, generator expressions are generally preferred over `map`, which is considered deprecated by some Python prominents.

Comment: @ThijsvanDien In 3.x this would be absolutely fine - easily replaced with `imap` or a `from future...` if desired...

Comment: @JonClements I thought it was a matter of style rather than efficiency or the like.

Comment: @ThijsvanDien there's little in it, but `float` and `map` being builtins can go to the implementation level... so have the potential to be faster

Comment: @ThijsvanDien wrong, `map` is preferred by a lot of people in the small cases where you aren't creating a `lambda` for it. It's also faster in these situations.